# wordpress remove parent 'require_once'

Tags: php, wordpress

In my **parent theme** functions.php I have this required_once:

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/customizer.php';
```

I would like to remove this from my **child theme**, without having to edit my parent theme functions.php.

Neither `required_once` or the `/includes/customizer.php` content is part of a pluggable function

Answer (score 2):

If the call to `require_once` takes place inside an action you may have the option to remove it.

It's likely however that isn't the case and there's no way to prevent it from being called from the child theme. Instead you're limited to undoing the actions and filters it introduces.

Answer (score 2):

For cases where you want to require/include PHP files, but still allow child themes to replace those PHP files outright, then you should use the locate_template function.

Example: Parent does this:

```
locate_template( 'admin/file.php', true );
```

This finds the admin/file.php file in either the child or the parent theme, then does a require on it (that's what the true is for).

So to replace the file in the child, you just replace the file in the child. Simple. Easy.

Note: The method defaults to using require_once. If you just want to require only, then pass a third parameter of false.